# Removing collection view header if collection view is empty

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

How can I remove my collection view header if the collection view is empty? I was able to programmatically add a label if the collection view is empty in my collection view file but I can't seem to find out how to remove the header.

```
 let messageLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20.0, y: 10, width: self.collectionViews!.bounds.size.width - 40.0, height: (self.collectionViews?.bounds.size.height)!))
 messageLabel.text = "No info yet"
 messageLabel.font = messageLabel.font.withSize(20)
 messageLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: messageLabel.font.pointSize)
 messageLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
 messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
 messageLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
 messageLabel.sizeToFit()

self.collectionViews?.backgroundColor = blue
self.collectionViews?.backgroundView = messageLabel
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can achieve that like this:

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

        if collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section) == 0 {
            return CGSize.zero
        } else {
            let headerView = self.view.subviews[0].subviews[0] as! UICollectionReusableView
            let existingSize = headerView.frame.size

            return existingSize
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is hiding not removing.

Comment: actually it's removing, returning CGSize.zero will make the collectionview not even call the datasource method to dequeue a header.